# Is there an example project that contains Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I wonder if anyone ever posted an example project that uses Core Plot?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the best website for iOS development tutorial.
Here is the simplest core data example what you are looking for, with great explanation and source code.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

Hope this helps.

Comment: The tutorials of Steve Baranski are absolute greate! and the best thing, there are all up to date and not from an old beta version of CorePlot. I used them in CorePlot 1.1 and everything works on the fly!